# Get UIBezierPath Stroke's Outline Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpath

I have a `UIBezierPath` stroke, now I want to get the stroke's outline path(not the stroke's path itself), is there a way I could get that? or at least `NSLog` the `UIBezierPath` stroke's outline path? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` for this.

```
UIBezierPath *path = ...;
CGFloat lineWidth = 10;
CGPathRef cgStrokedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path.CGPath, NULL,
    lineWidth, kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinRound, 0);
UIBezierPath *strokedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgStrokedPath];
```

Comment: Remember to call `CGPathRelease(cgStrokedPath);`!